# Debian version usage statistics

Tags: debian, version, statistics

I'm developing a Linux application. I would like to figure out the minimum Debian release I should target depending on the version usage statistics.

There is a lot of such information for Windows and macOS. However, I was surprised when I didn't find it for Debian. Are there any resources where I can get the usage statistics for Debian releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main statistics regarding Debian version use are [the popularity-contest statistics](https://popcon.debian.org). If you scroll down to “Statistics per popularity-contest releases”, you’ll see what releases the systems reporting popularity-contest data are running. This doesn’t necessarily reflect the general Debian-using population.

I would recommend only supporting the releases which still have security support (Debian 10 and Debian 9, more if you consider LTS and ELTS).

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks!